# How to implement efficient algorith for calculating multiple distinct values for large dataset?

Tags: python, c++, pandas, performance

I am trying to find a fastest way to calculate a number of unique values in a huge table, where the number of rows can easily be between 100 million to 10 billion. In this particular case, I am dealing with 128-bit integers.

I'm trying to understand, why pandas approach achieves a better result (tested with 1 million rows) as it appears to make operations on columns level, which feels inefficient. How this should be implemented in c++? My initial attempt to create c++ version was extremely slow (slower than Python). I used std:set, std:pair and std:map.

The first attempt looks like this:

```py
import time
from collections import defaultdict as ddict
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([])  # Load table with two columns containing 128 bit integers.

class Timer:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.end = time.time()
        self.interval = self.end - self.start
        print("time elapsed:" ,self.interval)


with Timer():
    print(df['left'].nunique())
    print(df['right'].nunique())
    left_grp = df.groupby('left')
    print(left_grp['right'].nunique().max())
    right_grp = df.groupby('right')
    print(right_grp['left'].nunique().max())
```

Below is the pure Python example, which goes the array through row-by-row basis, which should to my understanding be more efficient. It is just 3 times slower than pandas version.

```py
with Timer():
    uniques1 = set()
    uniques2 = set()

    uniques3 = ddict(set)
    uniques4 = ddict(set)

    for i in range(len(ndarray)):
        uniques1.add(ndarray[i]['left'])
        uniques2.add(ndarray[i]['right'])
        uniques3[ndarray[i]['left']].add(ndarray[i]['right'])
        uniques4[ndarray[i]['right']].add(ndarray[i]['left'])

    print(len(uniques1))
    print(len(uniques2))
    print(max(len(v) for v in uniques3.values()))
    print(max(len(v) for v in uniques4.values()))
```

Any advice on how to implement the above pure Python code efficiently in c++? My attempt with c++ below.

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <map>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t> uint128_t;
typedef std::set<uint128_t> set128_t;
typedef std::map<uint128_t, set128_t > map128_t;


namespace nunique_highperf{
    int get_max(const map128_t& map) {
        int best = 0;
        auto it = map.begin();

        while (it != map.end()) {
            best = std::max(best, (int)it->second.size());
            it++;
        }

        return best;
    }

    void default_update(map128_t &map, uint128_t left, uint128_t right) {
        set128_t temp;
        map.emplace(left, temp);
        temp = map[left];
        temp.insert(right);
        map[left] = temp;
    }

    void uniques_from_table(uint64_t **sessions, int rows) {
        set128_t uniques1;
        set128_t uniques2;
        map128_t uniques3;
        map128_t uniques4;

        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
            uint128_t left = std::make_pair(sessions[i][0], sessions[i][1]);
            uint128_t right = std::make_pair(sessions[i][2], sessions[i][3]);

            uniques1.insert(left);
            uniques2.insert(right);

            default_update(uniques3, left, right);
            default_update(uniques4, right, left);
        }

        printf("%d\n", uniques1.size());
        printf("%d\n", uniques2.size());
        printf("%d\n", get_max(uniques3));
        printf("%d\n", get_max(uniques4));
    }
}
```

In actual implementation, there will be multiple columns (not 2 as in the example), from which the number of unique elements is counted, hence I'm not just asking the fastest way to calculate distinct values for a single column, but over multiple columns as well as column pairs.

EDIT: Added c++ code

Comment: It might be worth sharing that initial C++ attempt.

Comment: You should also look at `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Start by getting rid of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.  It is not proper C++.  It ruins portability and fosters terrible habits.  See [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I miserably failed in my attempt to use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was actually simple.

Replacing default_update function with this:

```cpp
    void default_update(map128_t &map, uint128_t left, uint128_t right) {
        set128_t temp;
        auto temp_pair = map.emplace(left, temp);
        temp_pair.first->second.insert(right);
    }
```

did the trick.